# Xcode stuck on loading screen on macOS Ventura

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-ventura

I upgraded my macOS to Ventura and Xcode just hangs on the loading indicator. I've uninstalled Xcode multiple times and installed again, same thing. When I check Force Quit, it shows Xcode as Not Responding. Can someone help me please? I have a very close deadline. I'm running Xcode on a MacBook Air 2020 with the M1 chip

Comment: Did you install Xcode through the AppStore or from a local file downloaded from the developer website?

Comment: I installed from the App Store

Comment: Is the Xcode version you got from the AppStore fully compatible with your OS version? I’ve had these conflicts in the past and have been very careful since before updating either one.

Comment: On the App Store, it says Requires macOS 12.5 or later. I use Ventura, so it should be compatible

Comment: Can you share with us both the Xcode version and OS version?

Comment: I'm not sure what the fix was because I tried a bunch of different things and something fixed it
(1) I uninstalled Xcode and downloaded from Apple Developer website     https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/
(2) Ran this in the terminal
        rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport
        rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ Device\ Logs
        rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
(3) Restarted my macOS
(4) Not sure which of these fixed it but yeah it's fine now

My Xcode version is 14.1 (14B47b) and macOS is Ventura 13.0

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me and took me several hours to figure out the issue.  For me, it was because I had synced my Desktop & Documents to iCloud on my old MacBook before transferring everything to my new MacBook Pro M1. The Desktop & Documents (Documents, specifically) contained my Flutter project.  xCode doesn't like cloud-based folders/files so it was stuck on "Loading".  I created the same project outside of my Desktop & Documents and it worked.

Comment: Whole day trying to fix , you save my day thanks so much